# Custom View with Keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, custom-component, android-relativelayout

I'm developing a custom component that extends Relative Layout, the behaviour is to put an "_" on each character of a mask defined, and when you type on keyboard it replace the "_" for the character, it is working fine, to show the keyboard, I implement focusListener and is ok, but because it extends Relative Layout I don't have the option inputType and imeOption.

Does any one knows how I can implement that option?

Comment: Why `RelativeLayout` and not `EditText`? If you were extending EditText, you could do this with just a TextWatcher.

Comment: @Karakuri I'm new in creating components, so, it was the easiest way to do it, because I needed to create a line like doted with "_", and to do that I create a View and place it at the bottom, if any one have other solution would be nice, I'm opened for suggestions: here is my code https://bitbucket.org/snippets/tiagoMissiato/kM7qp

Comment: `EditText` (actually `TextView`) handles a lot of the complexity in dealing with text processing. I think it's far better to extend that and only worry about changing how the text appears in the EditText, using things like `TextWatcher` and text spans.